# Do I need the open-sourced kendo.core.js when running widgets?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, open-source

So exciting to see Kendo-ui-core now open to the public. Now with the huge selection of widgets and resources inside the grunt built directory `dist/js`, I was wondering if need to include kendo.core.js when running the widgets?

Would I need to include this when creating custom builds? eg. `grunt custom: core,autocomplete,dropdownlist`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly include `core` in the custom build - all widgets depend on it so it will be included automatically.